# RabbitMQ with Docker for Windows server

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, windows-server-2016

I've installed Docker for Windows Server on an Azure Virtual Machine.

Now I'm trying to set up RabbitMQ using steps from

https://hub.docker.com/r/library/rabbitmq/

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

But I get error.

3: Pulling from library/rabbitmq
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries.

Here is my docker version info

Client:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-2
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   10e292d
 Built:        Thu Sep 21 19:58:53 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-2
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   777d4a1
 Built:        Thu Sep 21 20:08:05 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false

Any Ideas?

EDIT1: To enable experimental mode I've tried to add a file C:\ProgramData\docker\config\deamon.json and restart Docker service like proposed below.

Edit2:

Managed to run in experimental mode. But I still get the same manifest error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to start dockerd.exe using the `--experimental` flag

```
dockerd.exe --experimental ...
```

In you case you have `Experimental: false`

Comment: Docker is running as a windows service. I don't know how to enable experimental mode for this.

Comment: @fanvabra this is not well documented for windows, but for linux you can add `"experimental": true` to deamon.json. On windows this file is under C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json , I expect adding the flag there and restarting docker should work

Comment: thanks @yamenk, see updated question. It did not work.

Comment: @fanvabra after setting the falg, did you restart docker? `docker info` does Experimental false still show?

Comment: Experimental false still show when i use "docker version". I restarted by restarting the windows service. Any better way of restarting (using cli)?